# Distributing and maintaining excel-file

Tags: file-management, spreadsheet

I am responsible for a spreadsheet that contains a database of products and their properties. I need a way to distribute it to people in the organization.

Control over rights to write is important, version control is a plus.

What kind of solutions exist? Dropbox? :)

Comment: Even though it's generally used for source code, Git/Github might work for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable, a Spreadsheet control like [ejSpreadsheet](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/spreadsheet/protectsheet) can be used to host your own sharing and editing interface. You will be able to allow sheet or cell based editing for different users.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.